# Is Ubuntu better on battery than other OS's?

Tags: battery

nothing really to say here, except it would be cool to get some examples on what OS's might save me battery life and if you have any suggestions on apps that would save battery on ubuntu that would be awesome.

Answer (score 9):

Ubuntu uses more power on laptops than Windows 7 does, according to wikipedia. As wikipedia puts it: "Ubuntu has also been criticized for its poor battery life on Laptops and Netbooks, even as OEM on devices such as Asus's eeePC, when compared to Microsoft Windows 7, with Ubuntu having been shown to use between 14-56% more power. Ubuntu's developers have acknowledged and sought to solve the issues of power consumption in future releases."

However, to save battery life, some tricks are to turn down screen brightness, and when not needed, turn off WiFi or bluetooth. Hope this helps!

Comment: A Kernel update (Linux 3.2) which will be present for 12.04 (LTS) is meant to fix this problem. Amongst others. See here: http://goo.gl/z18sN

Answer (score 1):

I think Ubuntu does use a little more battery on laptops for it has more CPU and device usage.

I find it useful to run `powertop` as root to cut down on unnecessary battery use. But I prefer not to keep those settings permanent as it might affect the system performance as a whole as I am using my laptop with power supply connected to it.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu uses more power but you have options, you could decrease the power usage or for save more battery power.

One option is jupiter, this program allows you to change the performace mode in the laptop and you could use 3 performace modes to saving battery.

To install it is very simple, is just:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter

If you own Asus EeePC netbook, also install jupiter-support-eee - required for SHE (Super Hybrid Engine):

sudo apt-get install jupiter-support-eee

This si the source [www.webupd8.org](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/jupiter-applet-finally-available-for.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is a little worse on battery life than windows and mac os but mainly the problem is the actual Linux Kernel (sort of core of the Ubuntu system).

Actual version 3.0 of the linux kernel still has this problem.

With instructions on this [link](http://29a.ch/2011/10/14/review%3a-ubuntu-linux-on-thinkpad-x1) a managed to take batterly life from 2hs to 5hs+

It's specific to one laptop but some of the recommendatios are valid to any system.